# How do I forward requests from a Tomcat to another Tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, proxy, war

I have a Tomcat server with a website deployed on it. That website makes requests to an application that is hosted on the same Tomcat, accessible at the URL `localhost:8080/myApp`.

Now I have deployed `myApp` on another server instead, so I need `localhost:8080/myApp` to redirect all requests to my other server at `1.2.3.4:8080/myApp`.

How can I achieve this in Tomcat? How can I map `localhost:8080/myApp` to `1.2.3.4:8080/myApp`?

Comment: Tomcat is not the right tool to be used as a reverse proxy, you'll need to write a servlet for that. NGINX or Apache2 would do the job much better.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks. How would I go about doing that on apache?

Comment: There are many good guides on the web. You can start with the [official guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/reverse_proxy.html) and solve problems as they appear.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thank you. What about ha-proxy? I heard that is a Tomcat feature that does reverse proxying